# SQL Query - Far beyond me

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a racing series website where we tally points during the season and I would like to attempt to put the tie-breaking details in the query rather than building the logic in PHP.

Table structure:

```
users
---------------------
user_id
first_name
last_name

user_races
---------------------
ur_id
user_id
race_id

user_race_classes
---------------------
ur_id
class_id
points_earned
```

Currently we've only had 4 races, so I haven't had to implement the "top 4" part of the query (it's a volunteer position and I haven't had much time for it), but here is my current query:

```
SELECT SUM(urc.points_earned) as total_points,
u.first_name,
u.last_name,
u.user_id,
ur.ur_id
FROM user_race_classes urc
LEFT JOIN user_races ur ON urc.ur_id = ur.ur_id
LEFT JOIN users u ON ur.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN classes c ON urc.class_id = c.class_id
WHERE ur.race_id IN (SELECT race_id FROM races WHERE season_id = :season_id && start_date < NOW()) && urc.class_id = :class_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY total_points DESC
```

Only your top 4 results are counted (out of 8 races) and here is the actual wording from the rules on tie breakers:

*If there is a tie in the total points, the tie breaker will be determined by counting up your total number of race wins WITHIN the total number (for 2013 it would be 4 races) that counted toward your total points; then second place finishes, and so on until the tie- is broken. In the unlikely event that the tie continues down to the last race that counted toward the total points, the next highest finish OUTSIDE of the races that counted toward the total points is compared, then the next highest finish, etc.*

Can anyone offer any advice on what to learn or look into to attempt to accomplish this strictly with MySQL?

Edit: Data can be viewed here:

http://www.wcics.ca/standings.php

Cheers

Comment: probably be better off implementing this in client-side code than trying to come up with a query that could conceivably recurse itself down some unknown number of levels.

Comment: @MarcB I hear ya, and that's where I was original just going to start, but then I thought it must be doable in SQL and would be a good learning experience.  Just not sure where to start.

Comment: @LukePittman . . . Sample data and desired results would really help readers understand the rules better.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks... edited and added a link to the data as it is online.